# How to change Launch Screen Image on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

I'm fetching a splash image from the server. I want to apply the downloaded server image as my splash image. How can I change a splash image to an image downloaded from a server?

Answer (score 3):

Splash images need to be defined at the time of app creation. The first screen you see is static and disappears after the program has loaded. However, after the program loads, you can keep any splash screen you want. It just is not possible from the start as the app as it hasn't started yet. So no app processes, like fetching a splash image, for example, can run before the app is live.

Comment: Can't I change the image on the splash screen by making it a variable?

Comment: You can. But that will be once the app has finished loading. At this point, you don't need a splash screen since your actual app is already active. So the splash screen will automatically transition away in iOS when the app is fully loaded. One reason why you may want to keep the splash screen when the app has loaded is if you wanted to do more processing before showing the user the app. Eg, you had to load some data from an API and render it before the splash screen disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can drag and drop the imageView in your launch screen and then make outlet to a new file SplashViewController.swift.Then in your controller Calss you can set image programatically.